# git clone does not fetch all commits

Tags: git, bitbucket-server

I cloned a repo from BitBucket.

For a specific file, in the BitBucket interface, it shows the last commit as 4/14/17. When I use git log, it says the most recent commit was from 2/1/27 (the previous commit). If I attempt to checkout the file, it won't get the 4/14 commit.

Any idea how to get these changes?

Update:

`git show [missing-commit]` will give me the commit details, so my local git does know it's there.

However, `git log /path/to/file` while on the branch will show all of the commits except the one that's missing.

Comment: Are you looking at different branches?

Comment: Try run something like `git log --decorate --graph --oneline --all`, which will show all commits on all branches. Then you can decipher what's happening.

Comment: @edmundo, yes it's the same branch.

Comment: Did you try checking out the _remote_ branch instead?

Comment: @gilez The commit that shows on BitBucket does not appear in git log, even as part of the graph. The commit hasn't been deleted as it still shows in the server. The repo state that the BB Interface is displaying is not in sync with what local git is able to clone/fetch/check out.

Comment: @AmyCodes do you perhaps need to run a `git remote update` locally, to get your local version in synch with the remote?

Comment: @gilez I tried that and no luck there. If I show the commit itself, my local git can get the details, but it doesn't show up as part of the branch log. I've updated my question with that.

Comment: @AmyCodes It really sounds like your local branch is not tracking the correct remote, or not at all (so you're on the wrong branch really). Perhaps something in this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520650/make-an-existing-git-branch-track-a-remote-branch . Otherwise I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and could similarly find no explanation. Sourcetree, git and github desktop would only pull up to a previous commit. I did the following to fix:

1. Create a temporary branch from the branch from `dev` (the branch with the missing commits).
2. Perform `git clone <repo>`
3. `git log --graph --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit` to verify the new commits and the new branch are present.
4. Remove the temporary branch remotely.
5. Clone the repo into a new directory.

`push`ing new commits functioned again.

This may be a bug on Atlassian's side, since there's no reason why these steps should be necessary.